# Any leafy plant which can be grown "inside" the house and doesn't need much moving around for sunlight?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, creepers

I know about creeper "Money plant". Any other beautiful plants/creepers other than this which satisfy my conditions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following house plants all do well in varying degrees of shade:

**Light shade** (bright but no direct sunlight)

- Cyclamen (C.persicum)
- Kaffir Lily
- Cineraria
- Spider Plant (Chlorophytum) - very hardy - will withstand considerable neglect.
- Dracaena (but only D.marginata and D.fragrans varieties).
- Ficus (other than the tree types).

  **Semi-shade** (moderately-lit area)
- Chinese Evergreen (Aglaonema modestum). Very shade-tolerant. This all-green type will thrive in poorly-lit conditions, but the varieties with whitish leaves need a well-lit situation.
- Asparagus
- Dieffenbacchia
- Sweetheart Plant (Philodendron scandens)
- Ivy Tree (Fatshedera)

**Deep Shade**

- Aspidistra (I've had one in my hall, which is pretty dark, for many years and it is thriving).

Comment: Very very helpful. Thanks. I also want to know what are the disadvantages of having indoor plants, should I start a "new" thread for it?

Comment: Glad you found the answer helpful. Yes, if you start a new thread, I'll try to think of all the drawbacks :)

Comment: I have the tubelight burning for at least 6 hours at night daily, will the effect any of those semi shade plants?